# Find nearest polygon on svg

Tags: jquery, svg

https://codepen.io/jriggs/pen/YVPvwv

Clicking on the colored part of "Childrens Learning Center" works as expected, but clicking on the text returns the letter path object, I want to get the polygon that contains the text

```
 $("#svg_id > *").click(function () {
   ...do stuff with $(this)
}
```

The problem is that there are  shapes for text 'on top' of the polygon so when I click on them they are selected and not the polygon. Clicking on

I need something like getParerent for svg. I can also edit the svg code if necessary

I have tried to use polygon as the selector, and also jQuerys closest:

```
$(this).closest('polygon')
```

And also messing with z-index properties with no success. The file was given to mefrom a designer so if there is a way to export in a more jQuery friendly format that may be an option. The image itself is a floorplan with many shapes and layers.

Comment: Post a complete example please, or a CodePen.

Comment: complete example of what?

Comment: Like to enable me to see the HTML... How can I tell you why `.closest` doesn't work? Is the text at least a child?

Comment: sure thing, editied - first line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target the clicked element in a SVG...
You should use the event target.

I don't know what you wish to do...
So I just console.log the clicked ellemet `class` and `tagname`.
To make more obvious visually, I change the `fill` color to cyan.

See in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NjPzvP?editors=1111).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Layer_1").click(function (e) {

    var eventTarget = $(e.target);

    var clickedClass = eventTarget.attr("class");
    var clickedTagname = eventTarget[0].tagName;

    console.log("\nA click occured on: " + clickedClass)
    console.log("Which is a: " +clickedTagname);

    // Action if target is not a paths (assuming those are all letters) and is not text
    if( clickedTagname != "path" && clickedTagname != "text"  ){
      eventTarget.css({"fill":"cyan"});
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: This has the same issue. Click on a letter inside a room and it will change that letter's fill color. I only want the room's polygon color to be updated. If a letter inside a polygon is clicked update the containing polygon color.

Comment: You will have to give a particular class to the `paths` which are letters. Then using a `if` condition, you can filter them. Some `path` aren't letters... so... No choice.

Comment: Assuming all paths were letters, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: I edited... You have at least one `path` that is a zone... ==> Library.

Comment: I still want to update the parent/container polygon fill color when a letter is clicked. Possible?

Comment: There is no parent / children in your code. Every elements are siblings. So this is hard to tell wich one is the "container". If you edit your SVG, in order to add a specific class to a container **and** order them so that the script only would have to look for the previous container class... This is possible.